# How to bind class to more than two options in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css, class, vue.js, binding

I have the following Vue.js bound HTML:

```
<span :class="[obj.status === 'Online' ? 'badge-success' : 'badge-danger', 'badge badge-pill']">{{obj.status}}</span>
```

I want to add another variant:

if `obj.status === 'Updating'` then the class should be `badge-warning`.

What is the best way to achieve this efficiently? I think I can add another ternary in the existing one but it will look messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span v-if="obj.status === 'Online'" class="badge-success">
   {{obj.status}}
</span>

<span v-if="obj.status === 'Updating'" class="badge-warning">
   {{obj.status}}
</span>

<span v-if="obj.status !== 'Updating' && obj.status !== 'Online'" class="badge-default">
    {{obj.status}}
</span>
```

You can conditionally render based on the status property.

The other way is to switch-case your class:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    obj: {
       status: 'Online'
    }
  },
  methods: {
  getBadgeClass(status) {
      switch(status) {
          case 'Online':
               return 'badge-success';
          case 'Updating':
               return 'badge-warning';
          default:
               return 'badge-default'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and then in your template you can do this:

```
<span :class="getBadgeClass(obj.status)">{{obj.status}}</span>
```

Comment: Do you know the performance of this vs doing it the method way?

Comment: It's the same as with the method way.

Comment: Marked as answer for the if-else solution because I think its the most clean, keeping the `CSS` out of `JS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another tertiary operator in case if Status is not online like below

```
 <span :class="[obj.status === 'Online' ? 'badge-success' : (obj.status === 'updating'?'badge-warning':'badge-danger'), 'badge badge-pill']">{{obj.status}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to shift your class assignment to a method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   myValues: [
       {status: 'Online'},
          {status: 'Updating'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
  assignedClasses(status) {
      var classToAssign; 
      if(status === 'Online'){
       classToAssign = 'badge-success';
      }
      else if(status === 'Updating') {
       classToAssign = 'badge-warning';
      }
      else {
       classToAssign = 'badge-danger';
      }
      
      return classToAssign;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(obj, index) in myValues" :key="index">
    <span class="badge badge-pill" :class="assignedClasses(obj.status)">{{obj.status}}</span>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to add multiple conditions can be like this

```
<span 
:class="[{'badge-success':obj.status === 'Online', 'badge-warning':obj.status === 'Updating', 'badge-danger':obj.status === 'Failed'},'badge badge-pill']"
>
{{obj.status}}
</span>
```